# py.checkio Solution syntax error with list

Tags: python, list, methods, syntax

This is a little disheartening as it's a trivial problem on the checkio python coding challenge site. The problem is [linked here](https://py.checkio.org/mission/all-the-same/solve/) I have the conceptual solution. I want to take the first element and see if the count(List) value is the same as the length of the list. If not, the answer is false. If the list is empty, it is given that the answer is true. Below is my code:

```
    from typing import List, Any


def all_the_same(elements: List[Any]) -> bool:
    listlen = len(List)

    if listlen == 0:
        return True

    else:
        if List.count(List[0]) == listlen:
             return True
        else:
             return False



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Example:")
    print(all_the_same([1, 1, 1]))

    # These "asserts" are used for self-checking and not for an auto-testing
    assert all_the_same([1, 1, 1]) == True
    assert all_the_same([1, 2, 1]) == False
    assert all_the_same(['a', 'a', 'a']) == True
    assert all_the_same([]) == True
    assert all_the_same([1]) == True
    print("Coding complete? Click 'Check' to earn cool rewards!")
```

this results in the error message :

```
TypeError: object of type '_GenericAlias' has no len(), all_the_same, 5
```

I'm learning python, coming from C/C++ and searching through python documentation, I can't ascertain the issue. I wrote this under the assumption that List is the list itself, and Any is the index variable.

Comment: `listlen = len(List)` should be `listlen = len(elements)`...`List.count(List[0])` is wrong too...

Comment: What about `return list(set(list)) == list`?

Comment: Got it. Was referencing wrong variable. That took a little too long.